# Apply Auto Width to an H1 Heading

Tags: html, css, width

How do i get an H1 heading so the element itself has its width defined by the amount of text used?

In the example below I want the red background to be the width of the title but can't seem to get this to play ball.

```css
body {width; 100%; margin: 0;}

.holder {
  position: relative;
}

#events {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <h1 id="events">FUTURE THINGS</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `display` type to `inline-block`

```css
body {width; 100%; margin: 0;}

.holder {
  position: relative;
  /* To center the text */
  text-align:center;
}

#events {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background: red;
    width: auto;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <h1 id="events">FUTURE THINGS</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to expand on this, if you also want to have the heading centred a parent element will need to wrap around the h1, set `width: 100%` and `text-align:center`

Comment: Thanks @Akshay.  I can't believe someone down-voted the question.

Comment: @TheChewy You're welcome :) , and the downvote, i  am not sure why

Answer (score 1):

you can use `display: inline-block` to achieve this

```
#events {
    margin: 1rem auto;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block; // Added
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `<h1>` is a block level element, it will occupy the full width of the container. If you make `<h1>` an `inline-block` or `inline` element, it will satisfy your requirement. But I prefer to add `<span>` inside `<h1>` and apply background color for that. So the `<h1>` remains as block element and which can be helpful in the layout. Since `<span>` in inline element by default, it will serve you with out any additional styles. You never need anymore wrapper for the `<h1>` to maintain the layout.

```css
h1{
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
h1 span{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="events">
  <span>FUTURE THINGS</span>
</h1>
```